# MariaDB MATCH AGAINST using + in BOOLEAN MODE

Tags: mariadb, query

I am having a problem with searching a MariaDB database.

Search keywords come from user-input, processed with PHP, SQL query made and results returned.

In it's simplest form :-

```
    CREATE TABLE db (
      item_no       SMALLINT(6) NOT NULL,
      item_text     MEDIUMTEXT,
      PRIMARY KEY   (item_no),
      FULLTEXT      (item_text))
      ENGINE=innodb";
```

I want to do an **AND** keyword search, such that more keywords give fewer results.
To do this I use the **MATCH AGAINST** query **IN BOOLEAN MODE**, putting
a '**+**' prefix to each keyword :-

```
    SELECT item_no FROM db WHERE MATCH (item_text) AGAINST ('+wordone +wordtwo' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

This words fine, as do literal searches :-

```
    SELECT item_no FROM db WHERE MATCH (item_text) AGAINST ('"wordone the wordtwo"' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

... however, if the last example is unquoted as :-

```
    SELECT item_no FROM db WHERE MATCH (item_text) AGAINST ('+wordone +the +wordtwo' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

I get no results. Is it because 'the' is a stopword ?

I am running MariadB 10.3.34 on Linux Mint 20.1.

Comment: (Your second query should give different results when the words are in a different order.  That is, your 3 queries are not equivalent.)

Comment: Thanks @Rick for confirming this is a stopword issue. To disable the stopword functionality, I eventually found the magic: `SET GLOBAL innodb_ft_enable_stopword = 'OFF'`  which does the trick. I could not set innodb_ft_enable_stopword in any configuration file, MariaDB says 'unknown variable' - a problem for another day.

Comment: Hmmm...  I see it here:  https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-system-variables/#innodb_ft_enable_stopword -- But, being "Scope: Global" probably means that you need to be root to set it _and_ it won't take effect until the user logs in again.

Answer (score 0):

True.  It cannot find any rows with "the" because "the" was never indexed because it is a 'stopword'.  The same goes for "words" that are shorter than `innodb_ft_min_token_size`, which defaults to 3.

I suggest you post a bug at bugs.mysql.com suggesting that "+" in front of a stopword or short word should not invalidate the entire query, but should simply remove the word from consideration.  (I think this is the way MyISAM's `FULLTEXT` used to work.)

Comment: As the question relates to MariaDB, the bug report should probably go to jira.mariadb.org :)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get around this issue by adding this text

`ft_stopword_file = ""`

to the .my.cnf file for MariaDB. I'd like to know why it's not working like it used to though.